# Error at the connection string (index 74)

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to the online mysql database, but my code fails with the error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 74

my connection string looks like this:

```
    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "111.111.111";
        database = "base";
        uid = "user";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "Server=" + server + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + password + ";";


        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    }
```

Comment: 111.111.111 is not a valid IP address. Do you have a server with this name?

Comment: I have correct ip adress there i just changed it at pastie..(its in format xx.xxx.xxx.xx

Comment: Have you tested it by having a raw string with those parameters, instead of concatenating?

Comment: Yes right now same error.

Comment: Could you show how you have declared the variable `connection`?

Comment: Here: http://pastie.org/private/4okhtgfajbkb4d9enfx3g complete db connect class.

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for the exception? That may help.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/pbqwxqncuju2pv77pyn5lg

Comment: I suppose that your database name, username and password are different from the example because the connection string resulting from that example has less than 74 characters. Is It possible that your password contains some `problematic` character? And could you stop to put your code in external links? There is an Edit button under your question text

Comment: Thath was the solution...My password had all kind of characters and all...Thanks!